# How to create an array from elements of another array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to filter an array to build another array with the results I get. But the combination of functions I have been using with jQuery haven't workk so far. So I would appreciate some advice about how to solve this.

Here is the example of what I'm trying to implement:

This is my first array:

```
var data =[salt.1200, salt.1100, salt.1000, salt.0900, salt.0800, salt.0700, current.1200, current.1100, current.1000, current.0900, current.0800, current.0700];
```

And from this array I would like to build two different arrays, one for salt and one from current.

I have tried to use a for loop with a jQuery grep function on it and split, but that didn't worked.

```
var plotsArray = [];
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            plotsArray = jQuery.grep(data, function(a){
                return (a.split(".") == 'salt')
            });
        }
        console.log('plotsArray: '+plotsArray);
```

Also, I been trying to do is to read the first part of the string until the dot and then build an array base on that result. Using for example array filter, but I haven't figure it out how to read just until the dot.

I will appreciate any guidance on how to solve this.

Regards,

Comment: Does `data` contain strings?

Comment: also doesn't a.split() return an array? a.split(".")[0] maybe?

Comment: @pimvdb, data contain strings.

Comment: @NickSlash, a.split returns an array with two elements from the string [salt, 1200]. And I want to get an array with all the salt elements. Make sense?

Comment: not really no? ([array] == [string]) == false

Comment: are the elements in your data array objects? or did you just forget the quotes? if there objects then your sort function will be run on their values and not the name itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something more along the lines off this.

```
var plotsArray = [];
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].indexOf('salt') >= 0){
            plotsArray.push(data[i]);           
        }
        console.log('plotsArray: '+plotsArray);
```

Comment: Dominic, thank you. Your answer was the first one I saw and the first one I tried and it worked ;) Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Make change here -

```
return (a.split(".")[0] == 'salt')
```

and your code will work.
Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lh8Pt/

Answer (score 1):

I reckon your test should either be:

```
return a.split(".")[0] == "salt";
```

or

```
return a.indexOf("salt") == 0;
```

The latter might be better because it will not error out in the occasion that one of the array values doesn't contain a dot.

Comment: The second one would work, the first has the same problem as the question, no index is specified so it compares the whole array to the string and will return false (unless the split returns an array with only one item)

Comment: My mistake.  I meant to add the [0] index and then must have forgotten it.  Added now.

Answer (score 1):

Using you code I would do:

```
var plotsArray = [];

plotsArray.push($.grep(data, function(n,i){
   return n.split(".")[0] !== "salt";
}));
```

And please be sure that the data array contains strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var saltArray = [];
    var currentArray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

        if(data[i].split('.')[0]=='salt'){

            saltArray.push(data[i]);

        }else{
           currentArray.push(data[i]);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter/map` methods you could do something like:

```
var current = [], 
    salt = data.filter(
            function(a){
              var x = a.split('.'); 
              if (/current/i.test(x[0])) { this.push(x[1]); } 
 //                                        ^ = current
              return /salt/i.test(x[0])
             }, current
 //             ^ context
           ).map(
             function(b){
               return b.split('.')[1]}
           );
```

[**MDN about Array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/afEGC/

```
var data = ['salt.1200', 'salt.1100', 'salt.1000', 'salt.0900', 'salt.0800', 'salt.0700', 'current.1200', 'current.1100', 'current.1000', 'current.0900', 'current.0800', 'current.0700'];

var asplit = new Array();
asplit['salt'] = new Array();
asplit['current'] = new Array();

​jQuery.each(data, 
          function(index,value)
             {
                 var split_value = value.split('.');
                   asplit[split_value[0]].push(split_value[1]);                                 
             });

console.log('salt: ' + asplit['salt']);

console.log('current: ' +​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ asplit['current']);​​​​
```